# WCF DataContractSerializer Performance with long property names

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

I am transferring large chunks of data over WCF, and I am trying to optimize the results sent. I have switched from NetDataContactSerializer to DataContractSerializer, but since it is no longer being serialized as XML, I wonder exactly what happens.

As an example, imagine I serialize a collection (100,000 records) of the following to XML:

```
public class SomeDataObject
{
    public string AnExcessivelyLongPropertyNameJustToIllustrateMyPoint { get; set; }
}
```

It would look something like this:

```
<a:SomeDataObject>
    <b:AnExcessivelyLongPropertyNameJustToIllustrateMyPoint>
        ABC
    </b:AnExcessivelyLongPropertyNameJustToIllustrateMyPoint>
</a:SomeDataObject>
```

Now, from the above, it is clear that for hundreds of thousands of records, there is a significant performance gain in naming the property something else, like this:

```
<a:SomeDataObject>
    <b:NormalName>ABC</b:NormalName>
</a:SomeDataObject>
```

My question is: When using a netTcp binding and the default DataContactSerializer, is it intelligent enough to not actually repeat the names of the properties being serialized?

Or if you don't know the answer to this, is there an easy way to measure this?

Comment: Not sure where you get the impression DataContractSerializer doesn't generate XML - MSDN says "Serializes and deserializes an instance of a type into an XML stream or document using a supplied data contract."  Sounds like XML to me.

Comment: @Tim: You raise an excellent point. I was under the impression that DataContractSerializer would use the BinaryFormatter internally. I can see that it does indeed not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For WPF serialization to have smaller XML add short name in `Name` attribute like:

```
[DataContract(Name="sdo")]
public class SomeDataObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "axlpnjtimp")]
    public string AnExcessivelyLongPropertyNameJustToIllustrateMyPoint { get; set; }
}
```

For manual XML serialization using `XmlSerializer` add attribute `[XmlType(TypeName = "x")]` for class and `[XmlElement("y")]` for properties.

In your case I would so something like:

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "sdo")]
public class SomeDataObject
{
    [XmlElement("axlpnjtimp")]
    public string AnExcessivelyLongPropertyNameJustToIllustrateMyPoint { get; set; }
}
```

And serialized xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<sdo>
  <axlpnjtimp>Property Name</axlpnjtimp>
</sdo>
```

It will reduce send data size considerably.

Comment: Using XmlType and XmlElement doesn't appear to work for the DataContractSerializer, but using `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "p2")]` does. This answer, combined with Tim's response to my question answers what I need to know. Adding shorter property names nearly halved the time it takes to serialize and transfer my data set when combined with `EmitDefaultValue`. Thanks to the both of you!